# Apple APNS and updated dev center agreements

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

We've been having trouble with our APNS push notifications.  It could be coincidence, but every time there is an update to the developer EULA, all push notifications stop working until accepting the agreement.  Is this expected, or am I just facing other coincidentally simultaneous problems?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but in my case APNS stopped to send pushes a couple of weeks ago without a reason. We have been using MoonAPNS interface since 2 yrs till now. Last year Apple changed SSL to TLS but this time must be another reason.